# NativeScript cant play multiple different videos on same page

Tags: nativescript, youtubeplayer

I have Angular Nativescript app with listview page that holds multiple YoutubePlayer videos on page.
When have multiple Youtube Player instances, player has its own videourl and the same api key as input. All videos are the same. I think it takes the first url, but inputs for url on each youtube player as inputs are different. Is api key for youtube unique per youtube instance or must each have its own api key? It appear like it is some kind of singelton instance per app.

Comment: Playing multiple video on same page is not supported by the plugin, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-youtubeplayer/issues/21). The author recommends playing the video in detail page, not on the list itself. Also he recommends using YouTubeThumbnailView for showing video thumbnails, but you might have to implement it natively at this moment.

Comment: Interesting. I do this in nativescript-vue and have had no problems. (yet).